# Traversing a "list" tree and get the type(item) list with same structure in python?

Tags: python, list, tree, traversal

"tree" structured list:

```
[(1,1,(1,1,(1,"1"))),(1,1,1),(1,),1,(1,(1,("1")))]  # may be more complex
```

1. How to traversing it and print each item - I means the 1 and the "1"?
2. How to generate type list with same structure?

   [('int','int',('int','int',('int','str'))),('int','int','int'),('int',),'int',('int',('int',('str')))]

   the 'int', 'str' here should be output of type(1) and type("s") as it can not been displayed on the question

Thanks!

Comment: fixed, but [(1)] can also been accepted in this list same as [1]

Comment: To flatten a "list of list" use [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

Comment: So for your second question, what exactly are you trying to do?  You just want to replace the "nodes" with their types?

Comment: @Jeff, yes, but I just find no simple way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a generator that will traverse the tree for you for (1).

```
def traverse(o, tree_types=(list, tuple)):
    if isinstance(o, tree_types):
        for value in o:
            for subvalue in traverse(value):
                yield subvalue
    else:
        yield o

data = [(1,1,(1,1,(1,"1"))),(1,1,1),(1,),1,(1,(1,("1",)))]
print list(traverse(data))
# prints [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '1', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '1']

for value in traverse(data):
    print repr(value)
# prints
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# '1'
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# '1'
```

---

Here is one possible approach to (2).

```
def tree_map(f, o, tree_types=(list, tuple)):
    if isinstance(o, tree_types):
        return type(o)(tree_map(f, value, tree_types) for value in o)
    else:
        return f(o)

data = [(1,1,(1,1,(1,"1"))),(1,1,1),(1,),1,(1,(1,("1",)))]
print tree_map(lambda o: type(o).__name__, data)
# prints [('int', 'int', ('int', 'int', ('int', 'str'))), ('int', 'int', 'int'), ('int',), 'int', ('int', ('int', ('str',)))]
```

Comment: thanks, 1 works and 2 is not what I want, but still useful.

Comment: I reread your question and think I fixed (2).

Answer (score 3):

You can walk any tree-like structure easily using recursion.  Just define a function that would look at all it's children.  Though traditionally, each child is itself a tree however in your case, it *might* be.  So I guess you could do something like this:

```
def traverseit(tree):
    if hasattr(tree, '__iter__'):
        for subtree in tree:
            traverseit(subtree)
    else:
        print(tree)
```

---

For your second question, assuming you just want to get a new "tree" that replaces the "nodes" with their types, simple:

```
def transformit(tree):
    nodetype = type(tree)
    if hasattr(tree, '__iter__'):
        return nodetype(transformit(subtree) for subtree in tree)
    else:
        return nodetype
```

Comment: thanks, I got the idea now, for q2, the point is, recursion if a node has `__iter__`, may I know if a class override the `__iter__`, what it will return?

Comment: @user: Both parts of my answer should allow any iterable object (excluding strings) to act as a tree.  So if you have any type that implements the `__iter__()` function, then it is considered a tree and will be used accordingly.  I wasn't sure if you wanted to restrict it to lists and tuples.  Do you only want lists and tuples be the trees only?

Comment: may no, I am in thinking now some other kind of class will be the item in this tree later. I just tested : no matter if I override __init___ or not in a class, your code will return the `type 'instance'`, that is OK, but for the dict type with actual data `{"a":1,"b":2}`, it will raise `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence `

Answer (score 0):

for #2 you can use this recursive lamba function and use it in map

```
   f = lambda o: (isinstance(o, tuple) and  tuple(map(f, o))) or type(o).__name__
   map(f, [(1,1,(1,1,(1,"1"))),(1,1,1),(1,),1,(1,(1,("1")))])
```

returns:
[('int', 'int', ('int', 'int', ('int', 'str'))), ('int', 'int', 'int'), ('int',), 'int', ('int', ('int', 'str'))]